# how to get ajax response to trigger click

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ajax

I have two forms for `buy now` and for `pincode` when I click `buynow` button sending request through `ajax` and same thing is done for `pincode` form also.

`HTML`

```
 <form method="POST" action="/cart/add" id="myForm"> 
  .....
  ....
  <input type="button"  class="buyNowBtn" id="btnBuyNow"/>
 </form>

 <form action="#">
     <input type="text" id="pinCheck" class="pinCheck" placeholder="enter pin code" />
     <button class="btn btn-info" id="pinCheckTest"> Check</button>
 </form>
```

In the same `buynow` click event I need to `trigger` a `pincode` submit button, so I did this

```
(document).on('click', '#btnBuyNow', function (e) {
    ....
    ....
    $("#pinCheckTest").trigger('click');
    ....

});
```

the above `trigger` event is successfully calling `pincode` click event

```
$('#pinCheckTest').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function (output) {
        if (output == 'true') {
            }
       else{
        }
    }
});
```

but I need to get `ajax` response back to `trigger` event so that I can do some operation is it possible?

something like

```
 (document).on('click', '#btnBuyNow', function (e) {
    ....
    ....
    $var output=$("#pinCheckTest").trigger('click');//I need to get ajax response back to this click
    if(output=='true'){
           ......
      }else{
       .....
      }
    ....

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a variable outside of both `click` handlers, when `.trigger()` is called, assign `$.ajax()` to variable, use `.then()` within first `click` handler to process results of `$.ajax()` call.

Note, included `event.preventDefault()` to prevent submission of `<form>`, as pointed out by @IsmailRBOUH

```
var dfd;
$(document).on('click', '#btnBuyNow', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ....
    ....
    $("#pinCheckTest").trigger('click');
    if (dfd) {
      dfd.then(function(output) {
        // do stuff with output
        console.log(output)
      })
    }
    ....

});

$('#pinCheckTest').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dfd = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function (output) {
      if (output == 'true') {}
      else{};
    }
  })

});
```

```js
var dfd;

$("#first").click(function() {
  $("#second").trigger("click");
  if (dfd) {
    dfd.then(function(data) {
      alert(data)
    })
  }
})

$("#second").click(function() {
  // do ajax stuff
  dfd = $.when("second clicked")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="first">first button</button>
<button id="second">second button</button>
```

Comment: By default, a button click submits the form and he thinks that the click event is not firing. He must prevent the default behaviour. Please check my answer.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Yes, see updated post; included `event.preventDefault()` within click handlers

Comment: @guest271314 do I need to assign `.then()` to variable like you assigned `.when()` to `dfd` or I can use directly `.then()`?

Comment: @subburoyal `.then()` is not assigned to a variable identifier, `.then()` is used to handle resolved or rejected `Promise` object or jQuery promise object. Use [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then) chained to `dfd`

Comment: @guest271314 instead of `ajax response` i am getting `object Object` to `dfd` what might be the reason?

Comment: @guest271314 thank you very much I got my `ajax response` I am checking `dfd` instead of `output`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are binding the click event to a `button` inside `form` you have the prevent the default behaviour which is 'submit the form'. Change you code to :

```
$('#pinCheckTest').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Your ajax call
});
```

Here is a demo to clarify the difference https://jsfiddle.net/qvjjo3jk/.

**Update1:**

Add an `id` to your form:

```
<form action="#" id="pinCheckForm">
     <input type="text" id="pinCheck" class="pinCheck" placeholder="enter pin code" />
     <button class="btn btn-info" id="pinCheckTest"> Check</button>
 </form>
```

Then:

```
$('#pinCheckForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: $(this).serialize(), //Sends all form data
        success: function(output) {
            if (output == 'true') {} else {}
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I need to submit `form` data need to check `pincode` availability in back-end. by taking the value form `text box`, if pincode is available i'll get `true` else `false` this response I need to get back to `trigger` event

Comment: Please check Update1